# Sharing dualboot volumes space-efficiently

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

I plan to dualboot my system [Ubuntu|Windows] using a small SSD. What are the options to save space? What I want is to have a either a \home as small as possible or a \home that I can use for both Ubuntu and Windows.

Should a use a virtual volume file inside NTFS partition as home folder? This would be great for flexibility. Is it possible to make it growing so I don't have to size it in advance? Or should I better use a small /home partition and store all big files on windows NTFS partition?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

*In Linux it's `/home` by the way*.

NTFS is bit different than the normal Linux filesystems. As a result *file system permissions* **do not work fully by default** if you use NTFS in Linux. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/62612) they can be configured but if this is your first time setting up a dual-boot, my advice is don't do it.

If you have some big files that you access from both Operating Systems, e.g. video, then you could achieve some space savings by putting these to a separate NTFS partition, or accessing the Windows NTFS partition from Ubuntu directly.